# How to make Video resume playing in Windows Phone 8 App XAML and C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone app that plays videos from a url on a video details page, I now have another page that users can navigate to from a click event to add comments to the selected video. But I discovered that, when users navigate to the comments page to post comments and click the phone's back button, the video does not continue to play, it just goes blank. I want to make the video playing to pause when users navigate to the comments page and resume, when the phone's back button is clicked. I am using Microsoft Media Player framework, and xaml and c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the Media Player's `Position` property in a variable, then check if it's already stored, and if so, use the page's `OnNavigatedTo` event to set the MediaPlayer back to the position and call `Play()`;